# Array problem getting both values

Tags: php, web-services, json

I have this array and I want to get both ID and Description from it. And all I get is Array Array Array... :-)

```
function getCountries() {
$json = file_get_contents('http://onleague.stormrise.pt:8031/OnLeagueRest/resources/onleague/Utils/Countries');
$data = json_decode($json, TRUE);
$countries = array(); 
foreach($data['data']['item'] as $item) {
    $countries[] = $item;
}
//print_r($countries);
foreach($countries as $v)
{   
    echo $v.'<br />'; 
    }
}
getCountries();
```

Comment: what was the result on `print_r($countries)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
foreach($countries as $v)
{   
    // I am assuming $v is an array with `ID` and `Description` in it:
    echo $v['id']."  ".$v['description'].'<br />'; 
}
```

This is bacuse the json for item is:

```
"item":
   [{"id":"DE","description":"Deutschland"},
    {"id":"ES","description":"EspaÃ±a"},
    {"id":"FR","description":"France"},
    {"id":"PT","description":"Portugal"},
    {"id":"UK","description":"United Kingdom"},
    {"id":"US","description":"United States"}]
```

where each item contains an `id` and `description` in an array

Answer (score 2):

You're getting that output because `$v` is an array, and you will have to reference the specific keys of `$v` to see the values, eg `$v['id']`. You can see the keys/values of `$v` are in your loop by doing `print_r($v);` instead of echo.

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $v['id'] . '-' . $v['description'];
```